# Mule 3.3 How to configure a cxf module at run time

Tags: runtime, cxf, mule

I want to know if it is possible to configure a cxf element at runtime , during running mule.

for example how it is possible to set "address" and "wsdlLocation"

Answer (score 0):

Both are not require ... either you can give wsdl location or address .. eg :-

```
    < cxf:jaxws-service wsdlLocation="wsdl/helloservice.wsdl" serviceClass="com.myapp.serviceA.IServiceA" doc:name="SOAP"/ >
```